# Meaning of Intercept Parameter in a Bayesian Longitudinal HLM

Tags: panel-data, multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian, jags, bugs

I have been working through John Kruschke's excellent book on Bayesian Data Analysis but now have found myself in experimental-design territory not covered in the book: a longitudinal linear mixed-effects model.

I would like to test the difference in linear trend over time between two groups. There is a two-level between-subjects predictor `XGroup`, a continuous within-subjects predictor `XTime`, and a subject-level predictor `XSubject`(equivalent of random intercept). I have included main effect and interaction betas for all of these variables, as well as the 'between x within' interaction `bBxW` and the 'subject x within' interaction `bSxW` (each participant's random slope).

My specification of the likelihood looks like this:

```
for (r in 1:nTotal) {
    y[r] ~ dt(mu[r], 1/ySigma^2, nu)
    mu[r] <- b0 + bB[XGroup[r]] + bW*XTime[r] + bS[XSubject[r]] + bBxW[XGroup[r]]*XTime[r] + bSxW[XSubject[r]]*XTime[r]
    }
```

The (inverse) link function specification `mu[r]` is what I am interested in here, especially what the `b0` intercept parameter represents. When testing HLMs using packages like `lme4`, when the model includes an interaction between categorical and continuous predictors, the estimate of the `(Intercept)` coefficient represents the estimated level of the outcome variable at the *reference level* of the categorical predictor when the continuous predictor is 0. However in the models I am used to from Kruschke's book, as far as I understand it, the `b0` represents the *grand mean*, which is the estimated level of the outcome variable *averaged across groups* when the within-subjects predictor is 0.

My questions are:

(1) what does the `b0` parameter in my model represent, the reference level or the grand mean?

(2) is the model specification equivalent to a random-slopes mixed-effects model, and if not, what do I need to change?